# Querying riak through curl blocking return

Tags: curl, riak

I'm relatively new to riak and am just in the process of exploring things
I seem to have this recurring problem thats an on again ..off again thing ..

**NOTE: This issue started after i tried setting up a mulit backend setup but reverted back to this one for now**

Everytime i start a riak node(i clear all the data in /var/lib/riak/) and try to perform a basic curl insertion on it ..

```
curl -v -XPUT http://10.151.99.77:8087/riak/test/doc?returnbody=true   
-H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{"bar":"baz"}'
```

(Taken from riaks tutorial)

The command just seems to halt or not return .. it has this message till the point it halts

```
* About to connect() to 10.151.99.77 port 8087 (#0)
*   Trying 10.151.93.77... connected
* Connected to 10.151.93.77 (10.151.93.77) port 8087 (#0)
> PUT /riak/test/doc?returnbody=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4     libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
> Host: 10.151.93.77:8087
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 13
```

my app.config is pretty basic with the exceptions .. 
 - Changed port to 8087
 - and i think this is default but the storage backend is {storage_backend, riak_kv_memory_backend}

and the vm.args has custom name with the ip of 10.151.99.77 ...
What i really want to know ..
 - is there some logs i can see for the curl commands ?
 - is there something im missing in the app.config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 8087 is the default port for the protocol buffer interface in Riak and will not serve HTTP requests. Instead try to connect to the default HTTP interface port 8098. If this doesn't work, check what the http parameter (available under the riak_core section of the app.config file) is set to and use this.

Comment: same issue ..different port .........................................

* About to connect() to 10.112.238.200 port 2100 (#0)  

*   Trying 10.112.238.200... connected  

* Connected to 10.112.238.200 (10.112.238.200) port 2100 (#0)  
> PUT /riak/test/doc?returnbody=true HTTP/1.1  

> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6   OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3  

> Host: 10.112.238.200:2100  

> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 13
>

Comment: Why are you connecting to port 2100 and not 8098?

Comment: i have something that was running on that port .. 
anyways .. it seems that its working now .. 
thanks .. :)

Comment: You can set the port by editing the following line '{http, [ {"127.0.0.1", 8098 } ]},' in your app.config file.